# Problems while compiling Qt 5.4.1 using Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, python-2.7, ninja

I am trying to build Qt, but can't solve an error coming up when I run 'nmake'.
I used this configuration:

```
configure -prefix %CD%\qtbase -debug-and-release -qt-sql-sqlite -no-audio-backend -no-declarative -mp -nomake examples
```

These options are compatible with MITK.
My Python version is 2.7.9 and I'm using Visual Studio 2013.

The error is the following:

```
Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 12.00.21005.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

    C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.4.1\qtwebengine\src\3rdparty\ninja\nin
ja.exe  -C C:/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.4.1/qtwebengine/src/core/Debug
ninja: Entering directory `C:/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.4.1/qtwebengine/src
/core/Debug'
ninja: fatal: CreateProcess: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.eb4b7f6c079ef7

NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.4.1\qtwebengine\sr
c\3rdparty\ninja\ninja.exe' : return code '0x1'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0
\VC\BIN\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '(' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue - I resolved after finding a clue somewhere (can't find the link) about this.

IF you go into

```
Qt\X.x\Src\qtwebengine\3rdparty\ninja
```

you will find a 'bootstrap.py'

I had to manually run boostrap.py.  Then, you should be able to re-run 'nmake' at the root of the Src tree.

Daryl